# Are "mid-derivatives" a thing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, probability-distributions

Many functions have simple expressions for their $n^{th}$ derivatives. For example, 
$$\dfrac {d^n} {dx^n} x^p = \dfrac {\Gamma(p+1)} {\Gamma(p+1-n)} x^{p-n}$$
for ${n = 0,1,...,p}$. Clearly, $n^{th}$ derivative functions like this can be interpolated. The function on the right-hand side can allow any real value of $n$ between $0$ and $p$ - not just integer-values. Is there some way to generalize the definition of derivatives to accommodate non-integer values?

I'm curious because any solution to this problem might help me find expectations of random variables raised to non-integer values. My thought being that some generalized derivative could be applied to the moment generating function in order to get the desired result.

Comment: The term you want to look for is "fractional derivative". There are a few different theories of fractional derivative. Usually at least one nice property of the usual derivative must be relinquished.

Comment: Look up fractional calculus. What you've done is the first step in that direction and indeed that is one common definition for a fractional derivative of a monomial. I have some notes that I could share with you that are a pretty decent overview. I'll have to dig them up though.

Comment: To follow up @Thompson's statement: fractional derivatives are non local, that is to say that they are not just dependent upon values in a small neighborhood of a point, but values over an interval.

Comment: Thanks! I've made several unsuccessful attempts to find/derive this over the years. Glad to finally have an answer. However, I'm worried that the non-local caveat might prevent a straightforward application to moment generating functions. Sounds like I should do more research on this before simply assuming it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a thing called fractional derivative and is a part of [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus).

In particular it is defined as 
$$ (D^n f) (x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^x (x-t)^{n-1} f(t) dt $$

Note however that there are left and right fractional derivatives which can in principle be different. See the link for more details.